# Spurious UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification notification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am able to register for UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification and properly receive events. But sometimes I receive these notifications **WHILE** the app is still running. I suspected memory problems to trigger an app resign/resume but could not confirm this was the case (I saw once a memory warning at the same time). Any reason why these methods would be called while the app is running (no call, no lock, etc.)?

I am registering for these notifications:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActiveNotif:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillResignActiveNotif:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
```

(This is done once in a singleton constructor using dispatch_once)

The corresponding functions:

```
-(void)appDidBecomeActiveNotif:(NSNotification*)notif
{
  NSLog(@"appDidBecomeActiveNotif called");
}

-(void)appWillResignActiveNotif:(NSNotification*)notif
{   
  NSLog(@"appWillResignActiveNotif called");
}
```

Here are some logs:

```
2013-04-11 09:28:11.401 App[1499:907] appWillResignActiveNotif
2013-04-11 09:28:13.505 App[1499:907] appDidBecomeActiveNotif
```

Comment: http://www.cocoanetics.com/files/UIApplication_Delegate_post_4_v121.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the docs says about those notifications:

> **UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification**
>   Posted when the application becomes active.
>   An application is active when it is receiving events. An active application can be said to have focus. It gains focus after being launched, loses focus when an overlay window pops up or when the device is locked, and gains focus when the device is unlocked.
>
> **UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification**
>   Posted when the application is no longer active and loses focus.
>   An application is active when it is receiving events. An active application can be said to have focus. It gains focus after being launched, loses focus when an overlay window pops up or when the device is locked, and gains focus when the device is unlocked.

So, are there any overlay window pop ups or are you locking the device or anything like that?

Also, why not use the methods in the AppDelegate to listen to those events?

**EDIT**

The problem, it seems, is MapKit's pop up asking the user to use it's location.

Comment: There is no overlay window (UIAlerts are not considered overlay popup I assume), no incoming message, call, no "select WiFi" window, nothing that is close to that, and also I do not lock the device, and it does not lock itself either.

Comment: I do not use the AppDelegate methods because I need that information in some other place and that's the supposed way to do. But that's a good point, I'll put NSLog statements there as well to check if the event is triggered.

Comment: I could actually pinpoint the problem, not an alert but MapKit! It seems to happen when the map is displayed. Further investigating the exact moment...

Comment: Or MapKit is loading too much info, causing memory problems?

Comment: Interesting new "feature" for Apple Maps.

Comment: OK my mistake - It was the "App wants to use your location" popup that was the problem - I was so much into it that I did not see it.

Comment: Please modify your answer to include that the problem could be a "(app name) would like to use your current location" - thanks

Comment: Found this interesting flowchart that explains it well: http://www.cocoanetics.com/files/UIApplication_Delegate_post_4_v121.jpg